# Scales = "free" works for facet_wrap but doesn't for facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to understand why the outputs of `facet_grid()` and `facet_wrap()` are different, even though the inputs are the same:

#### facet_grid

```
ggplot(temp, aes(x = valor)) +
geom_histogram(binwidth = 5, fill = NA, color = "black") +
facet_grid(estratificacao ~ referencia, scales = "free") +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 10)) + theme_classic()
```

[image]

#### facet_wrap

```
ggplot(temp, aes(x = valor)) +
geom_histogram(binwidth = 5, fill = NA, color = "black") +
facet_wrap(estratificacao ~ referencia, scales = "free") +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 10)) + theme_classic()
```

[image]

See, the argument `scales = "free"` does not have the same behaviors for `facet_grid()` and `facet_wrap()`. What can explain that?

Comment: There is always *lattice* package that [can do any free scales on grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7373238/673826).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Referring to [this link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/):

`facet_grid` split the data into facets by one or two variables that vary on the horizontal and/or vertical direction, while `facet_wrap` places the facets next to each other, wrapping with a certain number of columns or rows. In other words, `facet_wrap` only has horizontal dimension.

Therefore, using the example from that link, `sp + facet_grid(. ~ sex)` would behave the same as `sp + facet_grid( ~ sex)`. In your case, `facet_grid(. ~ referencia)` and `facet_wrap( ~ referencia)` should produce the same plot.

For two or more dimensional facets, `facet_grid` produces a grid of plots based on the parameter `(vertical ~ horizontal)`. `facet_wrap`, on the other hand, would just stack the plots horizontally. User then can set the layout by specifying the number of columns or rows.

Now, when the `scales = "free"` argument is added, facets in `facet_grid` would still be bounded by the grid, therefore plots on the same row cannot have different y-axis. Similarly, there can only single x-axis for each column. Using `facet_wrap` though, each plot is displayed independently, so it can "free" its x-axis and y-axis.

In my opinion, `facet_grid` is useful when you want to relatively compare the plots within a category, which can be accomplished by setting the same axis scales. Meanwhile, `facet_wrap` is more useful for plots that more independent between one another.

Comment: I always enjoying learning the theoretical foundations of the tools I use. Definitely will be helpful for me.